# Replacing multiple methods in sinon stub

Tags: angularjs, sinon

I have a Service - personService -  in my Angular application that has two methods getEverybody and getPersonById.
I can replace a method in my service using sinon stub like this:

```
var everybody = [...];
serviceMock= sinon.stub(personService, "getEverybody").returns(everybody);
```

How do I write if I want to replace both methods?
This does not seem to work:

```
var everybody = [...];
var aPerson = {...};
serviceMock= sinon.stub(personService, "getEverybody").returns(everybody);
serviceMock= sinon.stub(personService, "getPersonById").returns(aPerson);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax

```
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method");
```

returns a stub for the actual method and not the whole object.
You should write

```
getEverybodyStub = sinon.stub(personService, "getEverybody").returns(everybody);
getPersonByIdStub = sinon.stub(personService, "getPersonById").returns(aPerson);
```

and then you can write tests like this

```
describe('PersonService', function(){
  var personSrvc;
  beforeEach(inject(function (PersonService) {
      personSrvc= PersonService;
  }));

  it('should return all persons', function(){
      var everybody = [{name:'aaa'}, {name:'bbb'}];
      var getEverybodyStub = sinon.stub(personSrvc,"getEverybody").returns(everybody);
      var allPersons = personSrvc.getEverybody();
      expect(allPersons ).toEqual(everybody );
      expect(getEverybodyStub.called).toBe(true);
  });
});
```